# Capybara can't find element in template tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my page body returns this code

```
<template><h1>Hello world</h1></template>
```

but capybara can't find the element h1

this code does not work

```
assert_selector "h1", text: "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this myself as well, it seems capybara will remove the content from template tags while parsing it. So that would be the cause, still don't find a good walk-around yet.

ref:

- [github issue](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/2510)
- [commit for this behavior](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/commit/f23274e84a44cfe2b51607147dba4c151f735dee)